# Directly linking to an answer when the question has many pages of answers

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, answers, hyperlinks

I think directly linking to an answer, where the question of that answer has multiple pages of answers doesn't work - or at least doesn't work well.

For example, this link

[What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/1657050#1657050)

It doesn't get me to the right answer.

If it matters, I'm on Firefox 3.5.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works as long as the clicking user hasn't changed the default sort order of answers. By design, then.

Comment: And what is the default sort order of answers, by votes?

Answer (score 0):

Test:
[What's your most controversial programming opinion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406760/whats-your-most-controversial-programming-opinion/667637#667637)

That test works for me. Funny. Maybe the answer you link to was deleted?